# Passing credentials through Google App Engine to Google Reader

Tags: google-app-engine, google-reader, google-authentication

If I'm logged into an App Engine app using a Google Account, is there a way to pass those credentials through to another Google web application (like Reader) from the web app? I want the GAE application to be able to use data from my Google Reader without an additional authentication step (since I'm already logged into the GAE application).

Things I've tried and failed with:

1. Looked at whether the `google.appengine.api.users.User` class had anything I could use (didn't see anything useful for this purpose).
2. Passing through the ACSID/SACSID obtained from logging into the GAE application as cookies in the `urlfetch` call to https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/token;
3. Calling https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin with no parameters/headers in the hopes some magic might happen;
4. Calling https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin with ACSID/SACSID as above in the hopes some magic might happen;

**Update** I'm not trying to bypass authorisation - I simply want to reuse the credentials that the user has already entered rather than having a separate username/password form where they have to re-enter their credentials.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. The user did not explicitly authorize you to access their Google Reader data, so you cannot. You will have to go through a separate OAuth authorization step (once only) to get their permission to do so.

Comment: Well, I was actually looking at authentication rather than authorisation, but it may well be that the two parts are conflated in this scenario.

Comment: @TimDelaney Right - you've authenticated the user, but they haven't authorized you to access their data. If you could access a user's data in other Google apps without their explicit permission, that would be an enormous security hole.

Comment: Sure - no question there. I want to do the authorisation using the credentials they've already supplied - but as far as I can tell there's no way to do so.

Comment: @TimDelaney But that's my whole point - allowing you to do that would be an enormous security hole. It's not possible for a very good reason.